Running an application with an VPN in a systemd-nspawn container while host is using different VPN
My host is behind a NAT and connects to some other bastion host via wireguard, on interface wg0, with AllowedIPs set to 0.0.0.0/0,::/0, which routes all traffic through that bastion host.
Now, I'd like to run some application within a systemd-nspawn container, that uses a completely different wireguard tunnel: wg1. wg1 now should route all traffic (0.0.0.0/0,::/0) from inside that container. Additionally, I need to access ports from the host that the software in this container opens up.
What are the steps to create this container? Ideally, wg1 is created as a seperate tunnel "next to" wg0, instead of tunneling through wg0.
What I have done so far, without success:

create a wg1.netdev within /etc/systemd/network with:

[NetDev]
Name=wg1
Kind=wireguard

[WireGuard]
PrivateKey = redacted

[Peer]
PublicKey = redacted
PresharedKey = redacted
Endpoint = domain.tld:port
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25


configure the nspawn-container via /etc/systemd/nspawn/mycontainer.nspawn

[Network]
VirtualEthernet = true
Interface = wg1


within the container: /etc/systemd/network/wg1.network

[Match]
Name=wg1

[Network]
IpAddress = <v4 static subnet ip within wg1>
IpAddress = <v6 ...>


within the container: /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver <v4 dns advertised by wg1 subnet>
nameserver <v6 ...>


Enable systemd-networkd inside the container.
Enable ip-forwarding by net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 and net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1 (Not sure if this is necessary though?)

